# How to give the local zip path in AWS CouldFormation YAML CodeUri?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I have exported a lambda YAML from its export funtion using **Download AWS SAM file**.

Also I have Downloaded **the code zip file** from **Download deployment package**.

[image]

in the YAML file we need to give the `CodeUri`
in the Downloaded YAML it is `.` as shown in the below picture.

[image]

So when I upload it in the AWS CouldFormation it says:

> 'CodeUri' is not a valid S3 Uri of the form 's3://bucket/key' with
> optional versionId query parameter.

I need to know is there a way to give the zip file in the `CodeUri` from the local file path rather then uploading it in the S3.

I have tried with the zip file name I downloaded as well and still I get the same error.

[image]

Comment: @Marcin thank you for your answer. I'm new to AWS. what I understand from the package command is it will basically zip our code and upload it to S3. I need know if it is possible to do this without any interference of S3. I dont need to use s3 resource to keep my code. Just need to know if it is possible to upload from the local to the lambda. if it is possible could you please explain it with some example.

Answer (score 4):

You have to first run [package](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/cloudformation/package.html) command. It may not work with zip itself, so you may try with unpacked source code.

Comment: OP, This should be the accepted answer.